# Bootstrap lumen dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is the body element of my HTML inside _Layout.cshtml

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Power", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 44px, 0px);">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Power Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I have jquery-3.3.1.js and bootstrap.js in my project.

The dropdown list doesn't seem to be working.  Do I have to update the Jquery or any other script file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to update any script files. However, I found some markup problems in your existing code. Try to replace your `<nav>` tag with below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  @Html.ActionLink("Power", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
      <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
      <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 44px, 0px);">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqhenoox/677/